Laravel 11 Where to store init sql query with databsase mode settings
I need to run this sql
DB::statement("SET SESSION sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'");  // This is copy from MySqlConnector.php

It is modification of MySqlConnector.php::configureConnection() without ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. I wnat to use strict mode but without ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. ChatGPT lead me to add it to the AppServiceProvider::boot() method. Everything works BUT when I try to run our Bitbucket pipeline which contains command php artisan cache:clear it fails on error:
RUN cd /application && php artisan cache:clear
#21 sha256:1b4a053901e3fd6704ba3b6c9e8095bf143bba4784f432ebd7cb6e6bfe8b2fda
#21 0.513 
#21 0.513    Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
#21 0.513 
#21 0.513   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: SET SESSION sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION')
#21 0.513 
#21 0.513   at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:825
#21 0.518     821▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
#21 0.518     822▕                 );
#21 0.518     823▕             }
#21 0.518     824▕ 
#21 0.518   ➜ 825▕             throw new QueryException(
#21 0.518     826▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
#21 0.518     827▕             );
#21 0.518     828▕         }
#21 0.518     829▕     }
#21 0.518 
#21 0.518   1   [internal]:0
#21 0.518       Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}()
#21 0.519       +16 vendor frames 
#21 0.519 
#21 0.519   18  app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:36

It seems the connection is not resolved yet when cache:clear is called. The question is what is better place where to store this command to avoid this behaviour? Thanks.

Why do you want to get rid of only full group by in the first place? Otherwise, mysql config file (my.ini / my.cnf) is the best place to configure mysql connection properties if you want those to apply to every connection transparently and consistently.

I dont have access to my.ini. Its DO droplet with docker container.
